# PHP MYSQLI Get Rows But String With Comma [delete this]

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

hello here i have a string with comma and i want to select all rows in database table where is my string

```
$strings = '#a1 , #2';

$sql_query = mysqli_query($, "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE hashtag LIKE '%$strings%'");
while($fetch_data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_query)) {
 echo $fetch_data['hashtag']. '</br>';
}
```

my query show me blank...

i want to show
example:

```
#a1
#a1
#a2
#a2
#a2
#a2
```

[image]

Comment: String value is $strings = '#a1 , #2'; or $strings = '#a1 , #a2'; ?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commas don't have any special meaning in `LIKE` patterns, it won't look for matches of either tag. You need to split up the strings and search for each of them with `IN`.

```
$strings = '#a1 , #2';
$tags = array_map('trim', explode(',', $strings));
$tags_string = "'" . implode("', '", $tags) . "'";
$sql_query = mysqli_query($, "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE hashtag IN ($tags_string)");
```

Comment: Seeing the OP deleted their comment from here and seeing their desired output in the question, I figure that your answer (probably) didn't completely satisfy them by a probable missing ORDER BY (and/or) GROUP BY. Edit: I see they accepted your answer after all.

Comment: Good job seeing beyond the OP's request and giving them the answer they needed.

Answer (score 1):

This should have you covered on a multiple LIKE clause generator:

```
$strings = "#a1 , #a2";
$tags = explode(",", $strings);
$wheres = [];
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $tag = trim($tag);
    array_push($wheres, "hashtag LIKE '%{$tag}%'");
}
$where = implode(" OR ", $wheres)
$sql_query = mysqli_query($, "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE {$where}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below snippet:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT hashtag FROM my_table";
$result = $conn->query($sql_query);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["hashtag"].  "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: That isn't what the question is about.